# Sorbet generics question - method with type variable in parameter position

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I'm trying to get this Sorbet code working ([here](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0A%0Aextend%20T%3A%3ASig%0Aextend%20T%3A%3AGeneric%0A%0Aclass%20Foo%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3AGeneric%0A%0A%20%20TypeParam%20%3D%20type_member%0Aend%0A%0Aclass%20FooA%20%3C%20Foo%0A%20%20TypeParam%20%3D%20type_member%28fixed%3A%20Integer%29%0Aend%0A%0Asig%20%7Btype_parameters%28%3AMyParam%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20.params%28foo%3A%20Foo%5BT.type_parameter%28%3AMyParam%29%5D%29.void%7D%0Adef%20blah%28foo%29%0Aend%0A%0Amy_foo%20%3D%20FooA.new%0Ablah%28T.cast%28my_foo%2C%20Foo%5BInteger%5D%29%29) on Sorbet playground):

```rb
# typed: true

extend T::Sig
extend T::Generic

class Foo
  extend T::Sig
  extend T::Generic

  TypeParam = type_member
end

class FooA < Foo
  TypeParam = type_member(fixed: Integer)
end

sig {type_parameters(:MyParam)
      .params(foo: Foo[T.type_parameter(:MyParam)]).void}
def blah(foo)
end

my_foo = FooA.new
blah(T.cast(my_foo, Foo[Integer]))
```

However, I'm getting a type error:

```
editor.rb:23: Expected Foo[T.type_parameter(:MyParam)] but found Foo[Integer] for argument foo https://srb.help/7002
    23 |blah(T.cast(my_foo, Foo[Integer]))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Expected Foo[T.type_parameter(:MyParam)] for argument foo of method Object#blah:
    editor.rb:18:
    18 |      .params(foo: Foo[T.type_parameter(:MyParam)]).void}
                      ^^^
  Got Foo[Integer] originating from:
    editor.rb:23:
    23 |blah(T.cast(my_foo, Foo[Integer]))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Errors: 1
```

I'm not sure how to monomorphize the `blah` method so that it can take an argument of type `Foo[Integer]`. Does Sorbet currently support this use-case?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, and you want `blah` to *just* take an argument of type `Foo[Integer]`, you can do:

```rb
sig {params(foo: Foo[Integer]).void}
def blah(foo)
end
```

You can see a full example (with a type that doesn't conform to the interface [here](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0A%0Aextend%20T%3A%3ASig%0Aextend%20T%3A%3AGeneric%0A%0Aclass%20Foo%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3AGeneric%0A%0A%20%20TypeParam%20%3D%20type_member%0Aend%0A%0Aclass%20FooA%20%3C%20Foo%0A%20%20TypeParam%20%3D%20type_member%28fixed%3A%20Integer%29%0Aend%0A%0Aclass%20FooB%20%3C%20Foo%0A%20%20TypeParam%20%3D%20type_member%28fixed%3A%20String%29%0Aend%0A%0Asig%20%7Bparams%28foo%3A%20Foo%5BInteger%5D%29.void%7D%0Adef%20blah%28foo%29%0Aend%0A%0Amy_foo%20%3D%20FooA.new%0Ablah%28my_foo%29%0A%0Amy_bad_foo%20%3D%20FooB.new%0Ablah%28my_bad_foo%29)):

```rb
class Foo
  extend T::Sig
  extend T::Generic

  TypeParam = type_member
end

class FooA < Foo
  TypeParam = type_member(fixed: Integer)
end

class FooB < Foo
  TypeParam = type_member(fixed: String)
end

sig {params(foo: Foo[Integer]).void}
def blah(foo)
end

my_foo = FooA.new
blah(my_foo)

my_bad_foo = FooB.new
blah(my_bad_foo)
```